# Get a closer object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML dinamically generated:

```
...
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="q" value="5" name="q[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="p" value="20" name="p[]" /></td>
</tr>
...
```

Ok, so what I want to do is the following: when an input with class **q** changes, I want to obtain the product between **p** and **q** (**p*q**) that are in the **same** row, so in this example I would obtain 100.

Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.q').change(function() {
    result = $(this).val() * $(this).next('.p').val()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the other element with:

```
// this references the `q` element
$(this).parent().children('.p')
// or
$(this).next('.p')
// or
$(this).closest('tr').find('.p')  // <- least prone to structure changes
// or
$(this).siblings('.p')
```